# URL Redirects -- Amazon Platform to Magento

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

Our company recently switched from the Amazon Ecommerce platform to Magento. The developers we hired did all 301 redirects to our new homepage versus directing to the specific product or categories, which is hurting our SEO rankings. I do have a list of the old URL's that we were ranking for, however I cannot figure out how to retroactively redirect our old site which is no longer active to our new site on Magento. And I am not sure how redirecting would affect the initial 301 redirects. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you,
Jacklyn

Answer (score 0):

Yes. its possible.
If you have large number of URLs and you need to redirect it to corresponding pages in Magento, you could use below mod.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-s-mass-301-redirects-for-404-pages.html

We have been using this widely in our sites and it works well out of the box. You should definitely try this.

Comment: 301 redirects will also works fine. you can check in any one of the online reidrect checker to see. It will works for sure.